# Concatenar valores numéricos de varias filas en una sola en Python

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo 3 columnas con valores numéricos (floats) que me gustaría unir entre ellos. Es decir, que los valores de la columna 1, la columna 2 y la columna 3 queden en la misma columna 4.

He intentado con el siguiente código pero me da error porque no son strings...

`df["Columna4"] = df["Columna1"] + df["Columna2"] + df["Columna3"]`

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Buen día, deseas concatenar los valores o sumarlos? Es decir si tienes 1.23, 5.24 y 3.17 quieres obtener 1.235.243.17? ó 9.64?

Comment: Buenas! Me gustaría concatenar los valores, no sumarlos. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué significa "concatenar"? ¿Quieres que la columna 4 tenga una cadena como `"1.23 5.24 3.17"` o que tenga una lista de números como `[1.23, 5.24, 3.17]`? La cadena tendría una finalidad puramente visual, pues no es útil para operar con los números contenidos en ella. La lista en cambio te permitiría acceder a los números individuales o calcular su suma, su media, etc.

Comment: No necesito que se pueda operar sobre esa cadena ya que la finalidad es utilizarla como referencia para hacer 'merge' entre otros datframes. Sería como un número de referencia. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Columna4'] = df['Columna1'].astype(str) + df['Columna2'].astype(str) + df['Columna3'].astype(str)
```

o utilizando una función lambda:

```
df['Columna4'] = df[['Columna1', 'Columna2', 'Columna3']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.astype('str')), axis=1)
```